# ButterKnife in multiple activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, butterknife

This is the code that I try to use with ButterKnife but I got the following error when I run the project.

*error: cannot find symbol class Activity

error: package Activity does not exist

error: package Activity does not exist*

**BaseActivity**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResource());
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setupUI();
    }


    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

    protected abstract void setupUI();
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void setupUI() {

    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
}
```

**RegisterActivity**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.editText_username)
    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void setupUI() {


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_register;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

What's my mistake why I can't bind multiple Activities with the abstract class?

[Github Project](https://github.com/sssolammm/butterKnifleMultipleActivity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you don't need `Unbinder` for Activity`because Unbinder is only needed for`Fragment`.

**Second**, you better use another method to be override so that you don't need to set the `onCreate`. Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResource());
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setupUI();
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

    protected abstract void setupUI();
}
```

which then you can use:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void setupUI() {
      // setup the UI.
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
}
```

Here is the working example for using ButterKnife with abstract class:

https://github.com/isnotmenow/ButterKnifeAbstractSample

Comment: It don't work I remove onCreate from activities and I add the setupUI function but it keep droping the same error

Comment: Is your project work if you didn't use the abstract class?

Comment: It works If I dont use the bindings and I use the findByView. 

But if your question is If I remove the abstract class and I use the ButterKnife.bind(this) in the registerActivity the answer is no, It dont work I use the abstract class because I tought it will solve my problem.

Comment: Then, that it means your activity won't work when you applying butterknife on your plain Activity, right?

Comment: Yes it only works in MainActivity but If I create a new Intent to open new activity the bindings in the new one doesn't work. Using the same code as the first one ButterKnife.bind(this)

Comment: I have create a working project using the exactly the same solution in this answer. But I can't reproduce your problems. Perhaps something wrong with your project. Let me upload a sample for you.

Comment: Wait I will upload the project in github it will be easier for you to view my problem give me few time

Comment: Can you share you manifest? did you mention BaseActivity in Manifest?

Comment: I share all the project in github I'm checking your sample lets see what Im doing wrong

Comment: I checked manifest file and change it as @ישואוהבאותך does in his project but It keep throwing the same error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your example was perfect to found my multiple mistakes.